# JSON Deserialization to wrong object class passing

Tags: c#, json, .net

I have 2 classes that represent 2 Json responses in case of error or success.

```
private class SuccessResponse
    {
        public string message { get; set; }
        public bool sent { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
    }
```

and

```
private class ErrorResponse
    {
        public string error { get; set; }
    }
```

I use `try/catch` block to determine which kind of response is by trying to deserialize to SuccessResponse object, the idea is if it fails it's an ErrorResponse type of object and gets deserialized in `catch` block.

Json string looks like this: `{\"error\":\"Instance \\\"123\\\" doesn't exist.\"}`

This type of determination worked for me in the past projects, without any issues.

The problem is occurring in try block, deserialization to `SuccessResponse` is passing without any exceptions raised, object returned by deserialization is empty, having only default values, when it should be caught and deserialized in the `catch` block

I have tried, serializing it before deserialization, replacing backslashes with `""`, adding JsonProperty attributes, but it still keeps "passing" deserialization and returning an empty `SuccessResponse` object.

Here is the `try/catch`:

```
try
{
  var trySuccess = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SuccessResponse>(resp);

}
catch
{
  var tryError = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ErrorResponse>(resp);

  Log.Error($"ERROR FROM REMOTE SERVER: {tryError.error}");
}
```

Comment: _"when it should be caught and deserialized in the catch block"_ - why? By default serializer will just ignore missing fields and will throw for type mismatches for example when you try to deserialize object to collection and vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make one class ( use this code  or use inheritance after making classes protected instead of private)

```
private class Response
    {
        public string message { get; set; }
        public bool sent { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string error { get; set; }
    }

        //or 

private class SuccessResponse:ErrorResponse
    {
        public string message { get; set; }
        public bool sent { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
    }
```

and  code

```
var result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(resp);

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.error) Log.Error($"ERROR FROM REMOTE SERVER: {result.error}");
```

Comment: `SuccessResponse : ErrorResponse`  this even looks wrong)

Comment: @GuruStron You would be right if it was a painting that goes to the wall. I don't know where OP uses this classes else.

Comment: Yep, this works, for some reason, I overcomplicated this, one class is enough, thank You!